# CAn i Call a MVC POST controller method in jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-ajax

For some time I am worknig in MVC, I learnt from this post, 
http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/asp-net-mvc-partialview-with-ajax/#comment-435

that to load a usercontrol using AJAX, ww can use jquery, but Jquery is only taking GET Controller method name, Can I call a POST controller method name using JQUERY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [jQuery has a `.post()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for submitting POST requests to a server resource.  Note that it's just a wrapper for [the `.ajax()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Thanks David.. I guess this will work,type:'POST' should work

Comment: But David, could you tell me, how can i Pass an Object of a model as a 'data' in jquery?

Comment: @user1158326: The `data` element in the `.ajax()` call is just a key/value pair, generally given in JSON notation.  For example, a couple of values can be passed like this: `$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );`  Or an array can be included: `$.post("test.php", { 'choices[]': ["Jon", "Susan"] });`  So in the JavaScript code you'd just build a JSON object to pass to the request.

Comment: David, I found another way to do so, I used this statement - data: $('#frmId').serialize(), this way i dont need to pass single single parameter, actually my view was binded to the Model class, so I wanted those properties values in single object of that model class when I entered anything in the text boxes